# How can I send a hashmap over a channel?

Tags: multithreading, rust, hashmap, channel

I want to send a hashmap over a channel:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

pub fn frequency(input: &[&str]) {
    let handles = vec![];
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    for txts in input {
        let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
            tx.send(HashMap::new());
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
}
```

but the compiler won't let me:

```
error[E0277]: `Sender<HashMap<_, _>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:9:22
    |
9   |         let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Sender<HashMap<_, _>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Sender<HashMap<_, _>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&Sender<HashMap<_, _>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:9:36: 11:10]`
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
```

even though [there are Send and Sync implementations for HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-Send).

How can I send a hashmap over a channel?

Comment: The `HashMap` can be sent (if its key and value types are `Send`), but it's the *sender* (`tx`) that can't be shared between threads, which your code attempts to do. If you instead clone the sender (which just creates a new handle aimed at the same receiver) and move each clone to the thread, it compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f63817cde8efc8fef79c5dcf86e79e6a